# Item and Category database relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

So I would like to have users add an item and an arbitrary category. Right now I use if statements to make sure that if the category has been created already, not to add it again. Is there a better way to make use of SQLAlchemy relationships so that I could skip some of the logic I had to write to ensure that the categories are unique?

Here are the model's I used:

```
class Category(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'category'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)

class Item(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'item'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(250), nullable=False)
    description = Column(String)
    category_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('category.id'))
    category = relationship(Category)
    date_created = Column(DateTime)
    date_updated = Column(DateTime)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('user.id'))
    user = relationship(User)
```

Here is an example of how I would edit an item:

```
if new_category_name != category.name:
    if db_session.query(Category).\
        filter_by(name=new_category_name).count() == 0:
        new_category = Category(name=new_category_name)
    else:
        new_category = db_session.query(Category)\
            .filter_by(name=new_category_name).one()

    is_last_of_category = db_session.query(Item)\
        .filter_by(category_id=item.category_id).count() == 1
    if is_last_of_category:
        db_session.delete(category)
        item.category = new_category
db_session.commit()
```

Any other suggestions you are willing to make I am happy to listen to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `unique` constraint,

Quoting from sqlalchemy's [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.unique)

> **unique** – When True, indicates that this column contains a unique
>   constraint, or if index is True as well, indicates that the Index
>   should be created with the unique flag. To specify multiple columns in
>   the constraint/index or to specify an explicit name, use the
>   UniqueConstraint or Index constructs explicitly.

Example from sqlalchemy [documentation](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/constraints.html#unique-constraint):

```
from sqlalchemy import UniqueConstraint

meta = MetaData()
mytable = Table('mytable', meta,

    # per-column anonymous unique constraint
    Column('col1', Integer, unique=True),

    Column('col2', Integer),
    Column('col3', Integer),

    # explicit/composite unique constraint.  'name' is optional.
    UniqueConstraint('col2', 'col3', name='uix_1')
    )
```

Comment: So with this can I just get rid of my checks for a new category?

Comment: Yes, but you should give it a try, because it should throw and exception if someone tries to create a duplicate data, which you should be able to handle safely.

Comment: If I delete an item that happens to be the last of the category will it also delete the category automatically?`db_session.delete(user_object)`